# automatically generate RESTful API sample JSON

Tags: json, rest, documentation, dynamically-generated

I have some RESTful APIs on Jersey 2.17 with Jackson.
They are all on JSON style, and work very well.

But I want to generate a good RESTful Docs withJSON sample for developers.

So I tried some maven plugins,

Firstly I tried [ServiceDocGen Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/servicedocgen-maven-plugin/index.html),

it directly generate HTML docs with Json sample.
But it doesn’t know Jackson annotation like @JsonProperty, @JsonIgnore, 
So the JSON sample is inaccurate.

Then I tried [swagger-jaxrs-maven](https://github.com/greensopinion/swagger-jaxrs-maven), it knows some Jackson annotation like @JsonProperty, but still can't handle @JsonIgnore. Also it is the description of the data schema, not the sample. It will fail if the API directly return a JSON string.

I also tried jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin, it can only use JAXB to generate sample which is inaccurate.

Basically My requirement is simple:

1. Generate endpoint URL and parameter description from JAX-RS annotation, every plugins I tried did it very well.
2. Generate sample JSON on payload, I don't care JSON sample data logic is correct or not, I care if the data structure is accurate. So setting fixed data on certain type is OK, like ServiceDocGen always set "text" on a string.

I believe it is not so tough to generate JSON sample: Firstly go through Java Object tree, fill in random type safe data. Then call Jackson deserializer to generate json data.

But until now I can't find any maven plugin is doing this job well.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally finished my task by creating my own Java object creator.
To help other people who has the same issue, I added this project into GitHub:

[ObjectTreeCreator](https://github.com/Justin01Wu/ObjectTreeCreator)

After this project, the remaining tasks are simple:

1. find all API methods by Java reflection
2. find return class type on every API method by Java reflection
3. call ObjectTreeCreator to generate an object from the class type
4. call Jackson ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString to generate Json string from this object

Now my RESTful doc generator works very well. it only needs about 10 seconds to generate html document for about 300 RESTful APIs.

I also added into my maven build process. So every time my build server automatically find all APIs and generate RESTful doc for me.

The generated JSON structure is exact the same as real API response.

By the way I also used Integration testing result if it exists.

ObjectTreeCreator is only used when Integration testing doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can try spring-restdocs:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs

http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/

It generates documentation snippets based on tests of your endpoints (via RestAssured or MockMvc). This way you have a programmatic link between your code and your documentation.

Comment: Looks like it is promising. But how does it generate sample from test cases if test cases only cover some jsonPath rather than all nodes? Do you have some samples?

Comment: For example- you can document response fields by invoking assertion body("name of json field",expectedValue). What you are checking in your test case reflects what is generated.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you will find a tool out there that does exactly that. 
Your best bet is to write a `swagger.json` file and import the swagger-ui webjar dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger-ui.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You can then customize/override the index page of swagger-ui and hard code it to point to the localhost path to your swagger.json file or wherever you want.

If time is not a constraint, you could then write a maven plugin to scan and reverse engineer your JAX-RS annotations using reflection to generate a swagger json file. Personally, I prefer to maintain only a single json file and generate my API and models from that file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But most Java based RESTful API is generating JSON from Java object. so I will have a big trouble to align swagger.json to Java object in the future.

Comment: @Justin I'm not sure if agree with you when you say that most Java APIs generate their json docs from the Java objects rather than the other way around. Which APIs or usecase study are you referring to?

Comment: I ma using Jackson, it deserialize  a Java object into Json object

Answer (score 0):

I'd echo cosbor11's direction, Swagger is the way to go if you want to keep code and readable docs in sync. Check out Swagger Inflector which supports a service-first approach as described by Phil Hauer: https://blog.philipphauer.de/enriching-restful-services-swagger/

With Inflector, you can either start with API spec to generate stubs and proxies, or you can start service-first where your code annotations (see below) generates the Swagger spec for you:

```java
@Api(value = "customers", description = "RESTful API to interact with customer resources.")
@Path("customers")
public class CustomerResource {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get all customers", notes = "Get all customers matching the given search string.", responseContainer = "List", response = Customer.class)
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Customer> getCustomers(
            @ApiParam(value = "The search string is used to find customer by their name. Not case sensetive.", required = false, defaultValue = "") @QueryParam("search") String searchString,
            @ApiParam(value = "Limits the size of the result set", required = false, defaultValue = "50") @QueryParam("limit") int limit) {
        List<Customer> customers = dao.getCustomers(searchString, limit);
        return customers;
    }
}
```

Once you live in Swagger/OpenAPISpec land, there are a ton of tools (beyond swagger-ui) that help you generate static docs, interactive samples, and use whatever level of metadata/defaults that are in your Swagger spec to produce usable, human-readable examples.

- https://github.com/sourcey/spectacle
- https://lucybot.com/
- https://swaggerhub.com/

If you have problems implementing Inflector, definitely reach out to @olensmar on Twitter who works directly with @fehguy on the Swagger spec and tooling.